# getMapAysnc(this) crashes with NullPointerException

Tags: android, google-maps

I've been trying to setup a map using some help I got here. SO, it's very simple code but crashes. What am I doing wrong?

public class ShowDirection extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

```
private GoogleMap myMap;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.show_directions);

    MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);

    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this); // causes the Exception


}

@Override
public void onMapReady(final GoogleMap map) {
    this.myMap = map;

    myMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
}
```

Comment: Try changing `this` to `ShowDirection.this` and also post ur logcat pls

Comment: Do you have a fragment with the id = map? It causes the error cause mapFragment is `null`

Comment: @KISHORE_ZE that should not make any difference.

Comment: @Vucko - you're correct map was an id from some other layout that I was not using

Comment: Ok, i'll just move my comment to an answer then so u can close the thread :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Double check if your Fragment's id is actually `R.id.map` because it's returning `null` on that line. If it is not, simply replace that with the proper `id`.